# Is 1 point homogeinety (essentially) , with F(1)=1; F:[0,1]\to[0,1], equivalent to, Cauchy's equation and continuity, by itself?

Tags: linear-transformations, functional-equations, functional-inequalities, homogeneous-equation, cauchy-problem

It is said that a function is linear if if satisfies **Cauchy's equation (A)**:

(A)$$\forall(x,y)\,\in\,\mathbb{R};\quad  F(x +y)=F(x)+F(y)$$

**And 1 Point Homogeneity $(B)$:**

(B)$$ \forall \sigma , x\, \in \mathbb{R};\quad F(\sigma x)=\sigma F(x)$$

Then the function is already linear and continuous. $F(x)=ax\,;\,a=F(1);\, F(x)=F(1)\times\,x$

****Is not $(B)$  alone sufficient already for $F(x)=x$, over $[0,1]$ with  $\text{dom(F)}:=[0,1]$, with $F(1)=1$ without $(A)$ or continuity or anything else explicitely mentioned?**

That is,  if one If one could magically get to $(B)$, one would not need $(A)$;
 or  the superposition $(C)$:which is the admixture of $(B)$+ $(A)$

**$(C)$Superposition principle**

$$(C)\forall(x,y) \in \text{dom}(F)=[0,1]; \forall (\sigma_1, \sigma _2)\in \mathbb{R+}\cup {0}, ;\quad F(\sigma_1 x +\sigma_2y)=\sigma_1F(x)+ \sigma_2 F(y)$$

where $ (C)$ is the fusion of the $(B)$ and $(A)$, or convexity and concavity where $\sigma_1$, $\sigma _2$ but these do not need to sum to $1$ so that $F(0)=0$ is fixed, as for either $(A)$ or $(B)$

Under continuity or bounded assumptions Cauchy's equations $(A)$, which already satisfies  rational homogeneity $(D)$ and real valued additive rational superposition $(D1)$.

And can extended, given  entail $(B)$ under mild almost non-existent regularity requirements apparently; given the non negative domain and range.

$$F:[0,1]\to [0,1]\quad F(1)=1\quad 
\forall(x,y)\,\in\,\mathbb{R};\quad  F(x +y)=F(x)+F(y)$$

to entail $(B)$, homogeneity $\forall \text{real} \sigma $ as well as continuity anmd  $F(x)=x$
  $(B)$ as well

$(D)$ **rational homogeneity**

$$(D) \forall (x)\in \text{dom}(F); \forall \sigma\, \in \mathbb{Q}: F(\sigma x)= \sigma F(x)$$

$(D1)$ **rational superposition**

$$(D1) \forall(x,y) \in \text{dom}(F)=[0,1]; \forall (\sigma_1, \sigma _2)\in \{\mathbb{Q+}\cup {0}\}, ;\quad F(\sigma_1 x +\sigma_2y)=\sigma_1F(x)+ \sigma_2 F(y)$$

**Does not $(B)$  entail $(A)$ directly in any case over $[0,1]$ with $F(1)=1$ , 
One does not need , the superposition principle? $(C)$ above ,or $(B)$ plus $(A)$  to get that $F(x)=x$,  $(B)$ alone with  $F(1)=1$ with $\text{dom(F)}=[0,1]$ is sufficient?**

****Ie, doesn't $(B)$ alone directly entail  entail continuity, and the Cauchy's equation as well given $F(1)=1$ $\text{dom}(F)=[0,1]$and thus specify the function as $F(x)=cx$ where $c=F(1)$ directly**? At least under most circumstances and you are careful with the range and the domain. One does not need to specify $(A)$.

.

**One can resolve all irrational numbers, using the unit event if necessary.**
It essentially entails Cauchy's equation, in its most general form, and that the function is continuous; if $(B)$if it holds for real $\sigma$ and real $x$,

At least if you fix the domain and range, where $F$ is a function satisfying (1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$

$$(1)\text{dom}(F)=[0,1]$$

$$(2)F(1)=1$$ 
$$ (3)\forall (\sigma) \in \{ \mathbb{R}^{+} \cup 0 \}; \, \forall (x) \in \text{dom}(f)=[0,1];\, F(\sigma x)=\sigma F(x)$$

$$(1)F(x)=F(\,(x+y)\times\,(\frac{x}{x+y})\,)= (\frac{x}{x+y}) \times F(x+y)$$using real valued homogeneity, these are number in the non-negative reals
$$(1a)F(y)=F(\,(x+y)\times (\frac{y}{x+y})\,)= (\frac{y}{x+y}) \times F(x+y) $$
$$ [(1a)\land (1)] \rightarrow (2)$$ usin

$$(2)F(x)+F(y)=[(\frac{y}{x+y}) \times F(x+y)]+[(\frac{x}{x+y}) \times F(x+y)]=(\frac{x+y}{x+y}) \times F(x+y)\quad = 1\,\times F(x+y)=F(x+y)$$
$$(2)\leftrightarrow (3)$$
$$(3)F(x+y)=F(x)+F(y)$$

I presume that it entails Cauchy's equation in general, and can be generalized.

Wont the function= just be $$F(x)=x$$ over $[0,1]$, by definition ? 
Perhaps I am wrong here?

But I presume that real 1-pt homogeneity $(B)$in and of itself is sufficient,to get $F(x)=x$ without Cauch'ys equation $(A)$ above, being explicitly mentioned or any regularity requirement other then the domain, and $F(1)=1$ and $F$ is a function

Of course cannot usually get to $(B)$ except via Cauchy's equation $(A)$and a mild regularity assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one needs $(D1)$ to get to continuity and cauchy's equation as it somewhat specifies a linkage between the irrational $(x,y)$ to other rational or irrational $(x,y)$  via additivity and presumably just is cauchy's equation in an of itself. I presume it an accurate specification of jensen's equation with $F(0)=0$ where $\sigma_1, \sigma _2$ are not restricted to sum to one.

Does $(D)$ only specify additivity for $x,y \in $ irrational which add to an irrational value $x+y\in$irrational, but are rational multiples of each other?
So $(D)$ does not specify, real valued additivity where irrational $x,y$ sum to a rational and not, or irrational and are not multiples of each other. Unlike $(A)$, $(C)$, $(B)$ and $(D1)$ despite the fact that some of these only entail rational homogeneity they specify real valued additivity.

Does jensen's equation require any mono-tonicity assumption under the requirements;  with $F(0)=0$ or does it grant automatic continuity under non-negative domain and range.

$$F:[0,1]→[0,1]$$.
$$F(1)=1, F(0)=0$$
$$(3)∀(x,y)∈dom(F)=[0,1];F[\frac{x+y}{2}]=\frac{F(x)}{2})+\frac{F(y)}{2})$$

is $F(x)=x$
 immediate without further assumptions

And are both cauchy's equation and (jensens's  eq $(3)$ plus  $F(0)=0$)  then equivalent to, rational super-position to $D1$, above. Where the $\sigma$ are rational,  not need to sum to $1$ due to $F(0)=0$, and

is continuity automatic, without monotonicity or strict monotonicity, assumed, under $(D1)$ with $F(1)=1$ and $F:[0,1]\to[0,1]$

unlike rational homogeneity $(D)$ which would require
$$(A)F:[0,1]→[0,1]$$.
$$(B)F(1)=1$$

$$(C)F \, \text{where,monotonic increasing or strictly monotone increasing}$$
$$(D) \forall(x) \in \text{dom}(F)=[0,1]; \text{satisfies (D) above}$$

using the fact that $F$ above agrees with $F(x)=x$ over all rationals, a dense set of $[0,1]$ and as $F$ is strictly monotonic increasing, and  $F(x)=x$ is continuous, $F$ is continuous and identical to $F(x)=x$ over $(0,1)$,where one then puts in the specified end points as mentioned above.

; ,

Answer (score 0):

So as long as only considers the restricted range, it appears to just directly, Using $F(1)=1$ and 1 point homogeneity (B)to specify $F(x)=x$;

ie 
$$(1)F( x)=F(x \times1)$$

$$(2)$$
Letting $x= \sigma$, as $\sigma\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in [0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$ and a function, $F$ only has one value co-domain value, for each domain point.

For example, $\sigma=x\rightarrow F(x)=F(\sigma)=\sigma=x$

and using 1- point-homogeneity.

$$(3)F( x)= F(x \times 1)=x\times F(1)$$

Using $F(1)=1$.

$$4.F( x)=x\times F(1)=x\times 1=x$$

thus, $F(x)=x$

For instance if a function satisfies $F(\sigma x)=\sigma (x)$ for all reals in the domain $x$, and all ( non-negative, real numbers) .
 I am not sure, if $\sigma$ is restricted to rational numbers; that it entails Cauchy's equation.